# C++ dynamic byte signatures

Tags: c++

Is there a good way (or a good lib/class/source file/something) to, at runtime, find a byte signature (using a string of bytes) at a certain address and get a pointer to that address?

I.e. in running memory:

> ... 05 AE 6B 24 B1 00 B5 ...

and at runtime finding the first pattern of `AE 6B 24` and returning the address of the position?

Comment: You may want to look at `ReadProcessMemory` on Windows and `ptrace` on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking something like strstr, right? Try *memmem(3)*.

Comment: So theoretically I need to find the size of the module/address space I'm scanning for this to work, correct?

Comment: Yes, and also make sure you have proper access to that memory area.

Comment: `std::search` is more portable; `memmem` is a GNU extension, not part of the standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to make your search starting from memory address 3452345.

Create a `char *` by using `char *pMem =(char *)(*(3452345))`

Then loop over the memory using a char * to find the matching pattern.

However, this method is quite error prone (you can get errors while accessing some parts of the memory), you should handle errors.